# Retrieving data and displaying it properly

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a question regarding the retrieving data from another website.

My **Default.aspx** is like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInput"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" 
        onclick="btnSubmit_Click" /><br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResult1" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code behind it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        lblResult1.Text =
    wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://foo.com/servlet/AccessModule?id={0}&doc_type1=xyz&response=K", txtInput.Text));
}
}
```

It simply read the data from url above and display it on my page.

For example if i enter 12345678 in the textbox.

The result is something like this:

[image]

Now what i would like to do is making that last part of the result clickable. (http://foo.com/report/svc/id=000001DF-D80AB26F-C7D2-4FC3-ADD6-361E6630D572)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add < a > tag to String.Format

```
        Label S = new Label();

        S.Text = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://foo.com/servlet/AccessModule?id={0}&doc_type1=xyz&response=K", txtInput.Text));

        lblResult1.Text =string.Format("<a href='{0}'></a>", S.Text));
```

Comment: probably because you download a string.Try download it inside label and then lblResult1.Text = String.Format("<a href='labelText'></a>");

Comment: Sorry if this question too silly. Now i receive this message: The name 'labelText' does not exist in the current context

Comment: no it's ok :) i mean you can do technically like you did before
String.Format("<a href='{0}' > </a>",label.Text);

Comment: This time it says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'

Comment: main page works but it brings up an empty page when i enter a number and hit the enter.

Comment: hmmm i don't get what you mean ? try to debug and check the values returned from each step and tell me

Comment: Dear Ahmed. Thanks a lot for your help. I mean it doesnt bring any result. just an empty page. no error message and nothing.

Comment: Hmm when i checked the source page of the html seems like the url link is there. I guess the label is hidden or the font color is white or something like that.